# How can I write int value Binary and txt file in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct student
{
    int stuNum;
    int point;
};
int newStudent(FILE* dataf, FILE* indexf);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* datafile;
    FILE* indexfile;
    indexfile = fopen("indexDosyasi.txt", "a+");
    datafile = fopen("veriDosyasi.bin", "wb+");
    newStudent(datafile, indexfile);
    fclose(datafile);
    fclose(indexfile);
   
    return 0;
}

int newStudent(FILE* dataf, FILE* indexf)
{
    indexf = fopen("indexfile.txt", "a+"); // txt file
    dataf = fopen("datafile.bin", "wb"); // binary file
    if (dataf == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
        return -1;
    }
    struct student* last = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    printf("number of student \n");
    scanf("%d", last->stuNum);
    fprintf(indexf, "%d\t", last->stuNum);
    fwrite(last, sizeof(struct student), 1, dataf);
    // fwrite(&last->stuNum,sizeof(struct student),1,dataf);

    return 0;
}
```

Hi , i am trying student add system with c , my datafile have to be binary file and my indexfile have to be txt file , stuNum and point have to be int value but i cant add stunum and point into datafile and indexfile , i dont understand how can i add ? i read a lot answer about this question but i didnt find answer i want .When i run this code and enter the student number is 875,it says 66955608268424 in the indexfile(txt) and it says �*~ in the datafile(binary).i cant understand where is mistake?
Can you help me?

Comment: are you sure this the code you want to run? because i see this code can't run and it's messed up! for example, you're using in main function **indexfile** and **datafile** without pirior declaration.

Comment: this code is running but not true, i changed file and value name before i upload it in here so i might have done mistake . the shortest , i dont know how can i add int value of struct to txt and binary file with C , i read a lot answer about this question in here and google it but i cant find what i want answer, can you help me ? @walidbarakat

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: i use vscode @Armali

Comment: I read that [_VS Code is first and foremost an editor_,](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler) and asked "Which compiler do you use?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
int newStudent(...)
{
  write(fileName, "what you want to write", strlen("what you want to write"))
}
```

And if it doesn't works, try to tranform your int to a character string. I thing it is the itoa() or atoi() function.

Comment: nop it does not work unfourtunaly , output did not change .okay i will try itoa()

Comment: Did it worked with itoa?